# Direct Sum in Vectorial spaces find K values

Tags: linear-algebra

1.- Consider The Vectorial space $ V:= P_2\bigl(\mathbb{R}\bigr) $ and the Subspaces

$\bullet U = \{ p \in V: p(0)+p'(1)=0,p''(0)=0 \}$

$\bullet W_k =  \{ a+bx+cx^2 : a-Kb=0 \}$

a)Find the Value of the constant K such that U and $W_k$ are in direct Sum

b)Does it exist a value of K that $U+W_k = P_2\bigl(\mathbb{R}\bigr)$ ?

So basically my doubts are:
-I don´t know how to express the parameter derivatives of the U subspace $[p(0)+p'(1)=0,p''(0)=0]$, and how to express the derivatives as parameters that allows helps to form my conditions, but I remember the definition of Direct sum ;

+What is the condition necessary to acomplish: 
$U \cap W_k = \{ \Theta \}$  ?

And when I apply the definition of intersection , I made sloppy steps, because of the anterior questions,
thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to say that two vector spaces "are in direct sum"? What do you mean by "parameter derivatives"?

Comment: I mean that when these two vectors intersect each other, both conditions don´t match, and by ''parameter derivatives'' what I meant is I searched for p(x) : 1-x , but i can´t adapt to the Wk condition, i hope it's better

Comment: "I mean that when these two vectors intersect each other, both conditions don´t match...." You're going to have to do better than that, if you want to communicate mathematics effectively. I *think* what you're trying to say is that the only vector in both vector spaces (note: both *vector spaces*, not both *vectors*) is the zero vector, but I can't be sure. "I searched for $p(x):1-x$, but I can't adapt to the $W_k$ condition..." is also undecipherable. Please take the time and effort, when writing mathematics, to express yourself clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: Also, what does $S$ have to do with anything? You define it, then never refer to it again.

Comment: Also, is the constant $K$ the same as the $k$ in $W_k$? Are you using two different symbols to refer to the same quantity?

Comment: I have edited S, it has nothing to do in this exercise, and k is the same constant by letter but in different conditions, in my practice time (that university gives) my tutor , for example , changes the condition of p(0) in a polynomial of (0)^2+(0)x+2 with the form of ax^2+bx+c, that's my question , How to express P parameters in another way?

Comment: If $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then $p(0)=a(0)^2+b(0)+c=a\times0+b\times0+c=c$ (so I don't understand what $(0)^2+(0)x+2$ is supposed to be). I still don't understand your question(s). I don't know what $P$ parameters are, I don't even know what $P$ is, since there's no $P$ in the body of your question (although there is a $P_2$, and a $p$).

Comment: Well, that's right , i will say in another way, What can i do such that $U$ and $W_k$ conditions and their parameters, let's say, ($u in U$ and $w in W_k$), and put it together in the Definition of intersection, in this case, of two given subspaces ( For analyzing  if it's in direct sum)